# How to create custom form with list view

Tags: sharepoint-designer, infopath, custom-form

I got requirement from one of my customer to develop a form having relation between list and library in addition one list item having multiple relations/items in the library so. The customer require to view all information in one page.
For example.

- List: Contract (Having all details related to contracts)
- Library: Contract_Attachments ( having the all required documents with its properties and linked with ID from Contract list)

I would like to get the final display as shown in the below Picture.

Kind Regards

[image]

Answer (score 0):

From above screenshot it seems to be display form of a list Contract. So this will have listitem ID in URL querystring.

Now on this display form page. Go to edit page. Then add Querystring filter and Contract_Attachment library. Now connect a query string filter using ID from URL to the custome ID column(linked with ID from Contract list) in document library.

Here is reference for filtering using [QueryString filter](https://support.office.com/en-nz/article/Connect-a-Query-String-URL-Filter-Web-Part-to-another-Web-Part-8fd0107f-4889-451b-a7f7-d1996e12a8d1).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using query string filters I would suggest to use out-of-the-box webpart connections.
A short tutorial you will find in this video: [Youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cYU8bQ6Sw8I)

In your case the connections should be something like this:

Provider Field: Contract No (Contract Webpart)
Consumer Field: Contract No (Contract Attachement Webpart)

You just need to make sure that the 'Contract No' field for the library items is correctly set.